# How to subscribe to some Observable requests?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, angular8

I have a some http methods that returns Observable data. All methods are placed in service:

```
class Service {

    requests1(): Observable<any> {
        return http...;
    }

    requests2(): Observable<any> {
        return http...;
    }

    requests3(): Observable<any> {
        return http...;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in application I use it like:

```
Service.request1().subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

In nested component also call another request:

```
Service.request2().subscribe((data) => {
   console.log(data);
});
```

How to join them using forkJoin from different parts of application?

```
forkJoin(request1, request2) {}
```

Problem is that one `request1` is calling from parent component, another `request2` inside child.

I need joinFork to be ensure they are completed?

**I have idea to list all Observables like:**

```
export let request1Obs: Observable<any>;
export let request2Obs: Observable<any>;
export let request3Obs: Observable<any>;
```

Then in place where I call server to use:

```
request1Obs = Service.requests1();
request2Obs = Service.requests2();
request3Obs = Service.requests3();
```

And then child  `A component` to use this:

```
ngOninit() {
    request1Obs.subscribe(() => {});    
}
```

And in another child `B component` to use this:

```
ngOninit() {
    request2Obs.subscribe(() => {});    
}
```

And in parent component:

```
ngOnInit() {
   forkJoin(request1Obs, request2Obs).subscribe((data) => {
   // All requestes were finished in application
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay), the http requests will be executed only once then the forkJoin result will be cached for any new subscription in the whole app if the service is a singleton (just add `{provideIn: 'root'}`).

```js
@Injectable({provideIn: 'root'})
class Service {
    getRequestsData() {
        return forkJoin([...allRequests]).pipe(shareReplay(1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per correct usage of forkjoin you have to use it in a single source. Either you have to call your services from parent or from child. Then you can share data in between after completion of forkjoin.

In short in Parent component do this:

```
response1:any
response2:any
forkJoin(Service.request1(), Service.request2())
    .subscribe(Response =>
response1= Response[0];
response2= Response[1];
 );
```

After this you can send data(response2) to your child component in multiple ways.

Comment: I did not get this

Comment: You can call your all requests from parent component and store that data in parent component and send that data further to Component A and Component B using event emitters or output

Comment: I need to await until all requests are done, but forkJoin pushed last value from each requests

Comment: Official documentation for forkjoin says the same. It returns last value of each observable passed to it.Please find link of documentation : 
 http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin

Comment: Problem is that some requests sends in child components, some in other places. And how to listen if they are all completed? If I do forJopin() it also calls the same methods

Answer (score 0):

```
forkJoin(Service.request1(), Service.request2())
    .subscribe(([response1, response2]) => console.log(`response1: ${respone1}, response2: ${response2}`));
```

Comment: Yes, but shoud it be list of observables? Could you see my update